# SVN. Copy files and folders between repository folders

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse

I have a working copy which structure is similiar to this:

```
wc-root
     -folder1
     --trunk
     ---somefolder
     -folder2
     --trunk
```

How I can copy somefolder to folder2/trunk with all it's contents but without .svn files? Is it possible with SVN means? I tried to merge but failed.
I use eclipse with subclipse plugin.

**UPDATE**
I work with more complicated folder structure. Example:

```
     -folder1
     --trunk
     ---somefolder1
     ----file1
     ----file2
     ---somefolder2
     ----file3
     -folder2
     --trunk
```

Currently if I want to copy file1 and file3 to folder2 I had to create somefolder1 and somefolder2 under folder2/trunk and then make export to particullarly those folders.

What if I have >40 files in > 20 directories?

Answer (score 2):

**Export**

Use the 'Export' function to extract the files without the .svn files.

You can export directly into the correct location. On your next commit, Tortoise will recognise the new folder and allow you to add it to the repos.

Comment: Yeah currently I do in this way. But the problem is that I have more complicated folder structure than I drawn.

Comment: But what is the issue with a complicated file structure? Surely it still works?

Comment: yeah but for example if I select file1 and file3 and destination would be folder2/trunk the he will put file1 and file3 to folder2/trunk not to folder2/trunk/somefolder1/file1 and folder2/trunk/somefolder2/file3.

Comment: Can't you just export the whole of trunk, then remove any files you don't need?

Comment: Well yea, this is an option, but what If i don't want to rewrite some files? Uhm... oh it might be revert. Well thank you for help. Perhaps this is the best option.